# Combining multiple non contiguous ranges into one named range to clean up formula

Tags: excel, range

I have a formula that I'm using which works pretty well, but I would like to clean it up.

```
=SUMIF(IB02R, A56, IB02P)+SUMIF(IB03R, A56, IB03P)+SUMIF(IB04R, A56, IB04P)
```

`IB02R`,`IB03R`,`IB04R` & `IB02P`,`IB03P`,`IB04P` are ranges that I defined in the name manager. They look at entire rows.

`IB02R` looks at `B4-ND4` of another sheet
`IB02P` looks at `B5-ND5` of another sheet

and so on.

Here is the original formula:

`=SUMIF('2014'!$A$4:$ND$4,A75,'2014'!$A$5:$ND$5)+SUMIF('2014'!$A$7:$ND$7,A75,'2014'!$A$8:$ND$8)+SUMIF('2014'!$A$10:$ND$10,A75,'2014'!$A$11:$ND$11)`

I would like to simplify this to combine all R's and P's so instead of having 3 sumif statements I could just have `=SUMIF(IB0234R, A56, IB0234P)`. With `IB0234R` and `IB0234P` being the ranges contained within `IB02R` and so forth.

The formula is looks for a match between a particular cell and every cell in 3 different rows. Rows 4,7, and 10.

If there is a match anywhere within those rows it sums up the corresponding values in Rows 5,8, and 11 respectively.

Both of my formulas work, but I would like to simplify for sake of readability and clarity.

Is this possible? I've tried a few different ways to no success.

Comment: Not enough information to go on... We'd need to know what the inputs in the other 2 formulas are, I'd say... Maybe the easiest way to do this is to convert your named ranges into their Excel equivalent (eg convert `IB02R` to `B4:ND4`) and post **that** formula too, then we'd see if it could (1) Be consolidated (2) be converted into named ranges correctly.... Just my thoughts....

Comment: I have updated my post with further descriptions and the original formula.

Comment: I'm thinking this could fairly easily be done with a VBA function, but I'm not so sure this can be done with a direct Excel function with non-contiguous ranges... I'm looking into it, though... Would you be ok with VBA?

Comment: I'd be open to looking at it. I try to avoid VBA for sake of simplicity, but it would not hurt to see it, if you wish to post the solution with VBA.

Comment: Ok, it should be SUPER easy... I'll post it up in a tiny bit....

Comment: My answer has been fixed and is working now; sorry about the false start. I'll be interested to see the easy VBA solution though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT((CHOOSE({1;2;3},'2014'!$A$4:$ND$4,'2014'!$A$7:$ND$7,'2014'!$A$10:$ND$10)=A56)*CHOOSE({1;2;3},'2014'!$A$5:$ND$5,'2014'!$A$8:$ND$8,'2014'!$A$11:$ND$11))`

This will take a little bit of fancy named-range-fu to make it readable, but it's definitely doable.

First, combine the "first row" of each section together into another named range, like so:

`=CHOOSE({1;2;3},IB02R,IB03R,IB04R)`   -   We'll call this `IB00R`

Now do the same with the "second row":

`=CHOOSE({1;2;3},IB02P,IB03P,IB04P)`   -   We'll call this `IB00P`

Now the formula becomes:

`=SUMPRODUCT((IB00R=A56)*IB00P)`

To understand exactly how the formula is working, I suggest clicking Evaluate Formula on the Formulas tab, and stepping through it, and stepping in and out of your named ranges.

EDIT: <s>Ok now I'm doubting myself - not sure if this is working correctly. I know it will work because I've done it before, but the formula below may not be quite right. I'll figure it out in a bit.</s>

EDIT 2: <s>As written, this doesn't work. However, there is a way around the problem, but I can't remember what it is. Still fiddling with it. If I can't figure it out I'll delete this answer.</s>

EDIT 3: Working now. I forgot, in order to combine non contiguous rows you have to use `CHOOSE()` instead of `INDEX()` Sorry for the false start.

Comment: The edited version will work. I was using the wrong named range technique; sorry it's been a while since I've done this.

Comment: AWESOME!! - Definite +1!!! - **LOVE** the `CHOOSE({})` trick for naming dis-contiguous ranges - Never seen that before!!

Comment: I love it too, it's pretty cool. Wish I could remember where I saw it the first time so I could give credit where it is due. There is another way to do it using a bunch of `IFERROR()` statements strung together, but this way is better I think.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I **ABSOLUTELY** like Rick's answer a whole lot more, but I'll admit that what he did was new to me (which is why I love this site!!), so I only knew how to do this using VBA.

With VBA, the function you could use to do this would be as follows:

```
Function Disjoined_SumIf(CriteriaRange As Range, Criteria As Range, SumRange As Range) As Double

Dim ar As Integer
Dim cl As Integer

    For ar = 1 To CriteriaRange.Areas.Count
        For cl = 1 To CriteriaRange.Areas(ar).Cells.Count
            If CriteriaRange.Areas(ar).Cells(cl).Value = Criteria.Value Then Disjoined_SumIf = Disjoined_SumIf + SumRange.Areas(ar).Cells(cl).Value
        Next cl
    Next ar

End Function
```

And you would use it in your spreadsheet as `=Disjoined_SumIf(IB0234R, A56, IB0234P)`

This function will work based upon the following assumptions:

1. The criteria range is split up the same way the sum range is (which in your case it is)
2. It doesn't take into account things such as non-numeric data in your sum-range which would blow up the function

It's a quick and dirty solution that could be built upon to make it more robust, but it would work!!

So, again, I'd definitely go with Rick's solution, but I'm adding this for completeness' sake.